# deliberately failing a yacc rule

Tags: error-handling, grammar, yacc

in yacc/bison grammars, is there a way from within a mid-rule action to discard the rule 
altogether, but without an error (and the call to yyerror), so that other options would still 
be valid (similar to 'reject' in flex)?

assuming 'num' has an integer value, the following rule would then define different 
syntax for even and odd productions

```
rule :   num { if (($1 & 1) == 1) reject; } a b c 
       | num { if (($1 & 1) == 0) reject; } d e ;
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mid rule action to push a token to the parse stack, which can then be evaluated by another rule, which would make you able to make a programmatic choice regarding the outcome of the parse.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Actions.html

> The mid-rule action itself counts as one of the components of the
>   rule. This makes a difference when there is another action later in
>   the same rule (and usually there is another at the end): you have to
>   count the actions along with the symbols when working out which number
>   n to use in $n.
>
> The mid-rule action can also have a semantic value. The action can set
>   its value with an assignment to $$, and actions later in the rule can
>   refer to the value using $n. Since there is no symbol to name the
>   action, there is no way to declare a data type for the value in
>   advance, so you must use the ‘$<...>n’ construct to specify a data
>   type each time you refer to this value.

So, it might be possible to do so, but not in exactly the same manner as in flex. It's probably a bit hackish to do so, since what you are essentially doing is destroying the context-free nature of the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Yacc, unlike flex, does not do any sort of backtracking, so there are no other options at runtime -- either the rule running is correct, or there's an error.  You can use the `YYREJECT` macro to exit the parser completely (returning 1 from `yyparse`) but that's prbably not what you want.

If you were to use [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) (which supports backtracking), you could do what you want by calling `YYERROR` in a tentative action.  That will cause it to backtrack and try a different alternative and will only actually give a syntax error if there are no alternatives.